# Localization in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to change the button text using localization concept?

```
Ext.define("iPolis.view.login", {
     extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

     requires: [
         'Ext.TitleBar',
         'Ext.form.FieldSet',
         'Ext.field.Password',
         'Ext.field.Text',
         'Ext.field.TextAreaInput',
     ],
     id:'loginPanel',

     loginText:'Login',

     xtype:'login',
     .
     .
     .
     items: [{
           xtype: 'button',
           cls: 'btn',
           text: this.loginText,
           id:'loginbtn',
           handler: function() {

           }
     ]
});
```

My localization.js is like this:

```
if(Ext.form.Panel) {

Ext.override(Ext.form.Panel,{


    loginText:'iniciarsession'


});
}
```

I am getting a blank button. Please let me know what has to be done.

Comment: Ext.override is deprecated in Sencha Touch 2. Please use Ext.define instead. However, in this situation it's not necessary to use Localization if you just only want to set a new value for your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used it this way and it worked for me

```
var Messages = {

username: 'Benutzername',
password: 'Passwort'
login: 'iniciarsession'

}
```

and in the button definition:

```
                   {
                      xtype: 'passwordfield',
                      id: 'pwd',
                      placeHolder:'Password',
                      label:Messages.password


                    },
                   {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: 'btn',
                    text:Messages.login,
                    id:'loginbtn',

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used `loginText` as the button text but in when overriding it you have used `login`

so it should be

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Panel,{
    loginText: 'iniciarsession'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Ext.override` since it has been deprecated in Sencha Touch 2.

To achieve what you need, try this:

`Ext.getCmp('loginPanel').loginText = 'my new value'`

if it does not work, use this instead:

`Ext.getCmp('loginPanel').config.loginText = 'my new value'`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can use this method for buttons but i also have text boxes, labels etc. So i need localization